# mysql 5.1 -- unknown variable 'basedir=c:/mysql/'

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5, mysql-5.1

I recently changed the default port(3306) to another for mysql.
I did it by changing the my.ini file and did restart of the server.
No other changes were made whatsoever.
When connecting using a GUI no problem.
When I try using command prompt (mysql -u root -p) I get the following error.

mysql: unknown variable 'basedir=c:/mysql/'

Running on
Windows Server 2008 R2
MySQLServer 5.1

my.ini FILE info (removed some commented lines)

**[client]**
port= new_port

**##The MySQL server**
**Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.**
basedir="C:/MySQL/"
**#Path to the database root**
datadir="C:/MySQL/"
**#Set the default character set.**
default-character-set=latin1

**[mysqld]**
**#password=your_password**
port = new_port
**#socket = /tmp/mysql.sock**
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size=201M
**# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency**
thread_concurrency = 8

**#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.**
basedir = "C:/MySQL/"

**#Path to the database root**
datadir = "C:/MySQL/Data/"

**#The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when**
default-storage-engine=MyISAM

**# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will**
**# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with**
**# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the**
**# connection limit has been reached.**
max_connections=160

**# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value**
**# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.**
**# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files**
**# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in**
**# section [mysqld_safe]**
table_cache=320

**# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table**
**# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk**
**# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many**
**# of them.**
tmp_table_size=205M

**#Enable this option only if you would like to use InnoDB tables.**
skip-innodb
**#Don't allow new user creation by the user who has no write privileges to the mysql.user**   **table.**
safe-user-create
**#Start without grant tables. This gives all users FULL ACCESS to all tables!**
skip-grant-tables
**#Set the default character set.**
default-character-set=LATIN1

**# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1**
**# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set**
**# but will not function as a master if omitted**
server-id   = 1

**#If no specific storage engine/table type is defined in an SQL-Create statement the**   **default type will be used.**
default-storage-engine=myisam
**#Enable this option only if you would like to use InnoDB tables.**
skip-innodb
**#The number of simultaneous clients allowed.**
max_connections=160
**#The number of open tables for all threads.**
table_cache=320
**#If an in-memory temporary table exceeds this size, MySQL will automatically convert it**  **to an on-disk MyISAM table.**
tmp_table_size=205M

**#Don't allow new user creation by the user who has no write privileges to the mysql.user**   **table.**
safe-user-create
**#Start without grant tables. This gives all users FULL ACCESS to all tables!**
skip-grant-tables

**#Set the default character set.**
default-character-set=LATIN1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for posting the my.ini

**PROBLEM**: You have the basedir and datadir under the `[client]` section

`basedir` and `datadir` are server-only options, not client program options.

**SOLUTION** : Remove them from under the `[client]` section and you are good to go !!!

When done, this

```
[client]
port= new_port

##The MySQL server
Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/MySQL/"
#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/MySQL/"
#Set the default character set.
default-character-set=latin1
```

should now be this:

```
[client]
port= new_port
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Before anything, I was wondering why I'm getting that error if it was working just fine before I changed the port, and I only changed the port number. The basedir and datadir variables are in double quotes already.basedir="C:/MySQL/", datadir="C:/MySQL/Data". Even by specifying the port, I get the same error.

Comment: Please post the entire `my.ini` into the question.

Comment: Are there other my.ini files on the DB Server ???

Comment: No other my.ini file.

Comment: Updated my answer !!!

Comment: Crap,that's it! How did it got there?! I only changed the port. Working fine now. Thank you for your patience!